I can't understand the error of the code on Python: "destination computer rejected the connection request" with socket
I'm writing code on Python. The essence of the code is to create a server socket on one computer and turn it on, and on the second send a request with a message to the first computer and have it written in the terminal. But he gives me an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CTPAX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\ЕГЭ.py", line 87, in <module>
    sock.connect(('127.234.231.124', 55894))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] The connection was not established because the destination computer rejected the connection request

here is the code for the server socket itself:
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('127.234.231.124', 55894))
sock.listen()
print('Connected')
while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print(addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.send(data.upper())
    conn.close()

and here is the code for the client socket:
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.234.231.124', 55894))
sock.send(bytes('Hello, world', encoding = 'UTF-8'))
data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()
print(data)

I tried to change the operating system, change the host

Connection refused means that either the server isn't listening on that port, or there's a firewall blocking the connection.

Welcome to SO! I just edited the question title to be more specific. There's still room for improvement though; check out [ask] for tips.

Hi, Are you sure that you can bind to 127.234.231.124?  Locally socket could only bind to localhost `sock.bind(('localhost', 55894))

That's a loopback address (although 127.0.0.1 is more normally used for that purpose).  You cannot talk to another computer with such an address.

sry, yes, bind use 127.0.0.1 as an address. Everything else works. However you are not closing socket.socket properly and thus on the second run the port will be binned by zombie process. You won't be able to connect to the same port.

I'm not sure this is a software development question as such -- the same problem would happen trying to connect to a service hosted on another computer via a 127.x.y.z address using 3rd-party prebuilt software with no development activity involved.

@JohnnyCheesecutter, ...point is, 127.0.0.2 is just as much a loopback address as 127.0.0.1 is, and so is 127.2.3.4; the whole 127/8 is loopback. (Yes, that's a waste of address space, but back when IPv4 was established, that's not something people thought would be a problem).

@JohnnyCheesecutter, then I don't quite understand how to close it properly

@CharlesDuffy thx for explanation. Make sense to me. However on my mac this loopback doesn't work by default.

@JohnnyCheesecutter, fair; I know (much) more about Linux networking than MacOS.

@Barmar, nd how do I remove the restrictions?

Hello Timofey, I think you've missed part of explanation. IP address that starts with 127... can't be used to connect to other computer on the network. Computers in your internal network will have addresses starting from 192.XX.XX.XX or 172.XX.XX.XX or 10.XX.XX.XX. You need to know server IP address in the internal network which most probably will match one of this three patterns. Maybe @CharlesDuffy can comment on this. thx

@JohnnyCheesecutter I'm guessing the address is a virtual address for a docker container, venv, or something like that.

@ТимофейРачков It's your computer, don't you know how to configure its firewall? It's usually done with iptables.

@ТимофейРачков could you please clarify the situation. Are two computers that we are talking about in the same physical network or are we talking about establishing network between two docker containers running on the same laptop?

Are they on the same network? If that is the case, try fix the server’s bind to listen on the appropriate IP address or on all interfaces:
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 55894))

If that is not the issue, go to the firewall ports on both machines. You could also utilize ping to see whether or not you can connect using:
ping 127.234.231.124

If they are on different networks, make sure the server’s internet provider permits receipt of these types of connections from the port forwarding on the router.

ping 127.234.231.124 will succeed, but not because packets are successfully reaching the other computer: it's a loopback address, so (assuming absence of contrary configuration) the local network stack responds to it just as it would with ping 127.0.0.1.

idnk, but for me ping 127.234.231.124 doesn't succeed and ends with timeout. Maybe it is depending on your system.

@JohnnyCheesecutter It succeeds for me on Debian.

I have same recommendation as mentioned in the answers above. To make code workable use localhost or 127.0.0.1 for binding the server script and on the client side use network server IP (if server and client scripts are on running on the same computer use '127.0.0.1').
Also to note I would recommend you to use python context (with ... statement) for your server. In this way socket library will handle socket server closing automatically. If you won't properly close the socket server the port might have a zombie process stack to it.
import socket


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(('localhost', 55894))
    sock.listen()
    print('Listening')
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            try:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data: break
            except:
                break
            print (f"Data: {data}")
            conn.sendall(data.upper())


Insofar as the question talks about "the first computer" and then "on the second", I think the OP intends to use multiple distinct pieces of hardware? (If that is in fact the case, they shouldn't be using loopback addresses at all).
